# Accept user input and multiply by 0.00000116414, copy results to clipboard

Tags: javascript

This code pops up asking for the users input, and multiplies it by 0.00000116414.

I want to change this into a text input field and calc button, then perhaps add the ability to copy to the clipboard. How might I do this?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="Recommended Share Difficulty Calculator" content="[Share Dicciculty Calculator]" />
<title>Recommended Share Difficulty</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MathThing()
{
input = prompt("Enter your max KH/s.", "");
if (input==null || input=="")
{
return false;
}
share = 0.00000116414 ;
total = input * share;
alert(input + " * " + share + " = " + total);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:MathThing()">Calculate</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to manipulate the contents of a users clipboard you will need to utilize Flash. There is a great helper library called [ZeroClipboard](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/).  I've set up a basic [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/bpZh3/1/) (that uses your JavaScript) that uses this JavaScript:

```
var client = new ZeroClipboard(
$("#copy"), {
    moviePath: "http://zeroclipboard.org/javascripts/zc/ZeroClipboard_1.3.2.swf"
});

client.on('dataRequested', function (client, args) {
    client.setText((function () {
        input = prompt("Enter your max KH/s.", "");
        if (input == null || input == "") {
            return;
        }
        share = 0.00000116414;
        total = input * share;
        alert('"'+input + " * " + share + " = " + total+'" copied to your clipboard');
        return input + " * " + share + " = " + total;
    })());
});
```

This code follows the examples provided in the Zero Clipboard, the odd thing is it doesn't seem to work 100% of the time.  I do most of my work on computers that don't have Flash so I don't know if this reliability is part of the library or my computer.  Good luck.

Comment: I think this should work, if I can get the code below to work with this, it would be perfect! 

function copyToClipboard(text) {
window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text); 
}

Comment: I added a code example (and demo), but the strange thing is I'm not seeing it work 100% of the time when I click the button (despite being a rather simple example), maybe you will have more luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Copying cross-browser is tricky.

Here is some super-simple code showing an input + button use case:

```
var el = document.getElementById('input-id');
var sub = document.getElementById('submit-id');
var calc = function(e){
  var q = el.value;
  var share = 0.00000116414;
  if (q.length > 0){
    var res = q * share;
    alert(res);
  }
};
sub.addEventListener('click', calc);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G6T76/3/

You'll probably want to do a bit more validation on the input, though.

Comment: This is nice, but it appears the final numbers are too long? 0.0005820700000000001 how to cut down on some of those 0's?